# Omit / ignore any records that have been purchased by a user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently in the process of developing a site that amongst other things allows a user to filter a marketplace by showing or hiding items they have already purchased. This works on a basic AJAX call that passes through the current conditions of those filters available, and then using CodeIgniter's active record, it builds the appropriate query.

My issue is wrapping my head around the query so that if a user selects to hide purchased items the query omits / ignores any relevant records (i.e. if `user_id = 5` and hide purchased is true, any scenes that `user_id = 5` owns are not returned in the query).

**Tbl: scenes**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| design_id | scene_id | scene_name | ... [irrelevant columns to the Q] |
|-----------|----------|------------|-----------------------------------|
|     1     |     1    |  welcome   |                                   |
|     1     |     2    |   hello    |                                   |
|     2     |     3    |    asd     |                                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The designs table is very similar to this and includes references to the game, game type, design name and so forth.

**Tbl: user_scenes**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| design_id | scene_id | user_id | ... [irrelevant columns to the Q] |
|-----------|----------|---------|-----------------------------------|
|     1     |     1    |    5    |                                   |
|     1     |     2    |    5    |                                   |
|     1     |     1    |    9    |                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Query**

```
SELECT `designs`.`design_id`, `designs`.`design_name`, `scenes`.`scene_id`, `scenes`.`scene_name`, `scenes`.`scene_description`, `scenes`.`scene_unique_code`, `scenes`.`date_created`, `scenes`.`scene_cost`, `scenes`.`type`, `games`.`game_title`, `games`.`game_title_short`, `games_genres`.`genre` 
FROM (`scenes`) 
JOIN `designs` ON `designs`.`design_id` = `scenes`.`design_id` 
JOIN `games` ON `designs`.`game_id` = `games`.`game_id` 
JOIN `games_genres` ON `games`.`genre_id` = `games_genres`.`genre_id` 
WHERE `scenes`.`private` = 0 
ORDER BY `designs`.`design_name` asc, `scenes`.`scene_name` asc 
LIMIT 6
```

The query uses CodeIgniter's active record (`$this->db->select() / $this->db->where()`) but that is somewhat irrelevant.

--

I've tried things like an `INNER JOIN` with `user_scenes` and then grouping by scene_id, but that presents an issue with only returning scenes that are present in `user_scenes`. I then made an attempt at a subquery but then questioned whether that was the correct route.

I understand there are other ways - looping through the returned data and querying whether that record exists for a specific user, but that I suspect would be highly inefficient. As such, I'm at a loss as to what to try and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if your setup permits it, but I would do a subselect:

Either via a `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `scenes` 
    WHERE `scenes`.`scene_id` NOT IN (SELECT `scene_id` FROM `user_scenes` WHERE `user_id` = 5)
```

Or maybe via a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `scenes` 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT `scene_id`, `user_id` FROM `user_scenes` WHERE `user_id` = 5) AS `user_scenes`
    ON `scenes`.`scene_id` = `user_scenes`.`scene_id`
WHERE `user_scenes`.`user_id` IS NULL
```

Bit I guess the first way is faster.

Comment: Perfect. I ended up with: `$this->db->where('scene_id NOT IN (SELECT scene_id FROM user_scenes WHERE user_id = '.$user_id.')', NULL, FALSE);` I had tried something similar yesterday but for whatever reason I tried `WHERE 27 (user_id) NOT IN...`. Thanks for your help!